# Gradle transient dependency resolution: How to generically prefer `guava-jre` over `guava-android`?

Tags: gradle, guava

My project transitively depends on Google Guava lib. Suddenly (with new version of Guava?) the application crashes at startup with
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.stream.Collector com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.toImmutableList()'`.

In Guava 29.0, this method is [missing in `29.0-android`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.google.guava/guava/29.0-android/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html), but [available with `29.0-jre`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.google.guava/guava/29.0-jre/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html#toImmutableList--). Unfortunately, Gradle's dependency resolution chooses `29.0-android`.

In a first attempt I fixed it in `build.gradle` like this:

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
    // Because of java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.stream.Collector com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.toImmutableList()'
    substitute module('com.google.guava:guava:29.0-android') with module('com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre')
  }
}
```

Is there a more generic way to resolve this issue? If next Guava version `30.0-android/-jre` comes up, my solution has to get fixed again.

Comment: a link to this know issue with guava lib: https://github.com/google/guava/issues/2914  .  I think you don't have better alternative than declaring yourself a dependency to the `-jre` version and force this module in your build script, as described here : https://github.com/google/guice/issues/1207#issuecomment-423560702

Comment: Yep :( Someday we need to look into https://github.com/google/guava/pull/3683, which promises to make this better for Gradle users.

Comment: Thanks so far for posting the links.

Answer (score 1):

Until [PR-3683](https://github.com/google/guava/pull/3683) is merged in to make Guava publish Gradle metadata, which I am really looking forward to myself, you can use jjohannes' [missing-metadata-guava plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/de.jjohannes.missing-metadata-guava). It will retroactively add variants and capabilities to the Guava module metadata in Gradle. Along with some resolution rules, this ensures that the jre variant is selected even if a dependency transitively requests a (newer) android version.